# Apache RewriteMap not working to find url exist on external file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rewritemap

How to check url exist in some external file .

Just checking given request URI is in the list of vanity urls.

Vanity url's file present at /mnt/var/www/html/vanity_urls.txt

````
RewriteCond ${vanityurls:%{REQUEST_URI}|NONE} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond ${vanityurls:$1} >""
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1 [PT,L]```
Map filename contains same key value pair just for loading purpose to map . My use case is simply to check given request url is a vanity url or not.

Example - /clinicaltrials /clinicaltrials
````